How to keep the parent from changing sizes on child's :hover that changes its (the child's) size?
For reference, trying to replicate this dock effect on the Different By Design agency website:


Right now, I have a dock:
<div id="dock">
  <div><svg -- />
</svg></div>
  <div><svg -- />
</svg></div>
  <div><svg -- />
</svg></div>
  <div><svg -- />
</svg></div>
  <div><svg -- />
</svg></div>
</div>

And here is the CSS:
#dock > div > svg:hover {
  transform: translateY(-15%);
  height: 7vw;
  width: 7vw;
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out, height .1s ease-in-out, width .1s ease-in-out;
}

Since #dock > div > svg:hover changes the height and width of the svgs in question, it expands #dock. I would like the size of the dock to remain the same, as in the example link at the top.
I've tried making the :hover do position: absolute, but that just makes the dock not include it. I think I could set a width/height for the parent, however I'm not sure how to go about this or how to calculate the proper numbers for it to be dynamic.

For reference, the linked site uses a 3D translation to achieve the effect: transform: translate3d(0, -11px, 64px);

I can’t see the child’s size being changed, is it?

You could resize you hovered icons via a transform like transform: translateY(-15%) scale(1.5). Transforms won't cause layout shifts/reflows since the parent's  height stays the same. See codepen https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/qBGqRvZ

You should set the height, and width property on the initial svg elements, and apply transform on the hover state.


#dock {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: #ddd6;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
#dock > div > svg {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out;
}
#dock > div:hover > svg {
  transform: translateY(-15%) scale(1.25);
}
<div id="dock">
  <div><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18"><path d="M4.63 1h10.56a2 2 0 0 1 1.94 1.35L20 10.79V15a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4.21l2.78-8.44c.25-.8 1-1.36 1.85-1.35Zm8.28 12 2-2h2.95l-2.44-7.32a1 1 0 0 0-.95-.68H5.35a1 1 0 0 0-.95.68L1.96 11h2.95l2 2h6Z"></path></svg></div>
  <div><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18"><path d="M4.63 1h10.56a2 2 0 0 1 1.94 1.35L20 10.79V15a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4.21l2.78-8.44c.25-.8 1-1.36 1.85-1.35Zm8.28 12 2-2h2.95l-2.44-7.32a1 1 0 0 0-.95-.68H5.35a1 1 0 0 0-.95.68L1.96 11h2.95l2 2h6Z"></path></svg></div>
  <div><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18"><path d="M4.63 1h10.56a2 2 0 0 1 1.94 1.35L20 10.79V15a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4.21l2.78-8.44c.25-.8 1-1.36 1.85-1.35Zm8.28 12 2-2h2.95l-2.44-7.32a1 1 0 0 0-.95-.68H5.35a1 1 0 0 0-.95.68L1.96 11h2.95l2 2h6Z"></path></svg></div>
  <div><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18"><path d="M4.63 1h10.56a2 2 0 0 1 1.94 1.35L20 10.79V15a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4.21l2.78-8.44c.25-.8 1-1.36 1.85-1.35Zm8.28 12 2-2h2.95l-2.44-7.32a1 1 0 0 0-.95-.68H5.35a1 1 0 0 0-.95.68L1.96 11h2.95l2 2h6Z"></path></svg></div>
  <div><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18"><path d="M4.63 1h10.56a2 2 0 0 1 1.94 1.35L20 10.79V15a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-4.21l2.78-8.44c.25-.8 1-1.36 1.85-1.35Zm8.28 12 2-2h2.95l-2.44-7.32a1 1 0 0 0-.95-.68H5.35a1 1 0 0 0-.95.68L1.96 11h2.95l2 2h6Z"></path></svg></div>
</div>




I think that if plus to the translation effect, it would like to increase the size of the elements, it should be done by adding a percentage increment of with and height either. But it's just and idea that cross my mind as I ran the snippet.

@SIMBIOSISsurl yes, and using flex items can be sized dynamically.
